Recaptcha hitting OUR server with an api2/clr POST call (resulting in 404s)
Recently the last few days, we have been seeing a growing number of 404s all with the following format: (some stuff redacted)
1.1.1.1 - - [11/Jul/2024:14:00:56 +0000] "POST /recaptcha/api2/clr?k={our_site_key} HTTP/1.1" 404 5126 "https://{some_url_on_our_site}" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/17.5 Safari/605.1.15"
2.2.2.2 - - [11/Jul/2024:14:16:46 +0000] "POST /recaptcha/api2/clr?k={our_site_key} HTTP/1.1" 404 1698 "https://{some_url_on_our_site}" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/126.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/126.0.0.0"
3.3.3.3 - - [11/Jul/2024:18:08:07 +0000] "POST /recaptcha/api2/clr?k={our_site_key} HTTP/1.1" 404 1698 "https://{some_url_on_our_site}" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/126.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
4.4.4.4 - - [11/Jul/2024:18:13:37 +0000] "POST /recaptcha/api2/clr?k={our_site_key} HTTP/1.1" 404 1698 "https://{some_url_on_our_site}" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 10; K) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/126.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36"
5.5.5.5 - - [11/Jul/2024:19:11:10 +0000] "POST /recaptcha/api2/clr?k={our_site_key} HTTP/1.1" 404 1698 "https://{some_url_on_our_site}" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:127.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/127.0"
6.6.6.6 - - [11/Jul/2024:19:47:14 +0000] "POST /recaptcha/api2/clr?k={our_site_key} HTTP/1.1" 404 1150 "https://{some_url_on_our_site}" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/126.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"

As you can see, its a wide array of machines and browsers. That url doesnt exist on OUR server... that should be going to googles server, but for some reason it's not.
Also, we have not changed our integration of Recaptcha v2 Invisible for a long time now, so this 'new behavior' is not our doing (that we know of). I am also unable to reproduce this myself on my macs/pcs, but the amount of these are growing in frequency (maybe at some point I WILL be able to reproduce it).
Anyone have any ideas what may be going on here?

Edit: While doing a capture of the post body (php://input), the data it's trying to send to our server is an encrypted pile. Its a large amount of binary which needs a key (and neither our public nor secret google keys work that I've tried).

I don't have an answer, but we've been experiencing these too. The source IP appears to be a customer's browser, so I'm not sure what is going on. It appears that the Recaptcha JS is calling back to the server expecting this to be a live URL.

same exact problem here

We are seeing the same issue. The recaptcha script is sending an api request from the browser to a relative url at /recaptcha/api2/clr instead of an absolute(google) url for some users. When this happens recaptcha IS NOT WORKING. The callback js script is not triggered and our server postback does not include the recaptcha response token.

We've seen this as well the last few days, however, while investigating properly today I have the impression it stopped happening in the last 30-60 minutes or so, so I guess google pushed an update to their scripts to fix it. Do you guys see this as well?

there's an open incident at Google's Recaptcha service: https://status.cloud.google.com/incidents/MzARofVtutSd2HB5vmkT

Nice find! Ok, so this answer is kind of actually the most accurate to answer my question... as it shows "this is a google problem, they are aware of it, they should fix it".

Same bug on our site, firewall blocking a lot of people because of:

Request: POST /recaptcha/api2/clr?k={our key}
Action Description:Warning.
Justification:Match of "within %{tx.allowed_request_content_type}" against "TX:content_type" required.

We temporary disabled mod_security rule 920420 (OWASP3), and hope Google will sort it out.

Seems Google solved this incident:
https://status.cloud.google.com/incidents/MzARofVtutSd2HB5vmkT
We enabled the rule again, seems OK now.

Same bug on our websites.
POST on <websitedomain.fr>/recaptcha/api2/clr?k= is call by
https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/releases//recaptcha__fr.js
We have 404.
It happens on 20 websites on different hosting.
Bests,
Seb

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Same thing happening to us. We're using react-google-recaptcha-v3 library and at first I kept investigating on this level but there's no way this library is messing up with the URL. It must be a problem directly within the Google reCaptcha library so I feel like there's really nothing I can do.
